# adding average row to dataframe that include "-"

Tags: pandas, mean

I converted np.nan values to "-" and I want to add average row to my new dataframe but I do not get the average output.

```
date         col1  col2  col3
2019-10-10     5    2      4
2019-10-11     -    3      0
2019-10-12     7    -      -
2019-10-13     0    5      6
2019-10-14     2    -      3
```

This output that I want:

```
date         col1   col2  col3
2019-10-10     5     2      4
2019-10-11     -     3      0
2019-10-12     7     -      -
2019-10-13     0     5      6
2019-10-14     2     -      3

Avrg.         3.5   3.3    3.25
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with convert values to `floats` and `mean`  and add to last row with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
#if not DatetimeIndex
#df = df.set_index('date')

df.loc['Avrg.'] = df.mask(df == '-').astype(float).mean()
print (df)
           col1     col2  col3
date                          
2019-10-10    5        2     4
2019-10-11    -        3     0
2019-10-12    7        -     -
2019-10-13    0        5     6
2019-10-14    2        -     3
Avrg.       3.5  3.33333  3.25
```